# How to overwrite a PHPExcel method without editing the library ?

Tags: php, oop, phpexcel, overwrite

I'd like to overwrite the `PHPExcel_Cell_DefaultValueBinder::dataTypeForValue()` method WITHOUT touching the library PHPExcel, so that I would not have problems to upgrade the library later.

As a matter fact, I am doing this to solve a problem of convertion of numbers into strings and I just wanted to know how to overwrite a method so that I can continue using the library with no later problem.

Comment: Write your own value binder that implements the PHPExcel_Cell_IValueBinder interface, does your test in the bindValue() method and sets the cell if the match is met; but defaults to the default value binder otherwise - this is exactly what the advanced value binder does

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a new class which would **inherit** from `PHPExcel_Cell_DefaultValueBinder`, and **override** the function `dataTypeForValue`.

```
<?php
class PHPExcel_Cell_MyValueBinder extends PHPExcel_Cell_DefaultValueBinder {

    public static function dataTypeForValue($pValue = null) {
        if (/* your condition */) {
            // if you want to return a value, and i guess it's what you want, you can
            return PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::YOUR_TYPE;
        }
        // you call the fonction PHPExcel_Cell_DefaultValueBinder::dataTypeForValue();
        // so the already existant conditions are still working.
        return parent::dataTypeForValue($pValue);
    }

}
?>
```

After, just use `PHPExcel_Cell_MyValueBinder` instead of `PHPExcel_Cell_DefaultValueBinder`, using at the top of your code :

```
PHPExcel_Cell::setValueBinder(new PHPExcel_Cell_MyValueBinder());
```

So `PHPExcel` will use your own ValueBinder for the rest of the execution :)

Answer (score 4):

```
class PHPExcel_Cell_MyValueBinder extends PHPExcel_Cell_DefaultValueBinder implements PHPExcel_Cell_IValueBinder
{
    public function bindValue(PHPExcel_Cell $cell, $value = null)
    {
        // sanitize UTF-8 strings
        if (is_string($value)) {
            $value = PHPExcel_Shared_String::SanitizeUTF8($value);
        }

        // Implement your own override logic
        if (is_string($value) && $value[0] == '0') {
            $cell->setValueExplicit($value, PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
            return true;
        }

        // Not bound yet? Use default value parent...
        return parent::bindValue($cell, $value);
    }
}
```

Comment: But doing this, I still have to change the fromArray method.. So I have to do the same for that method

Comment: No @Periback, look my answer I explained how to do without having to edit fromArray. ;)

Comment: Nice shot, @JulienFouilhé! Even after creating the method, I didn't know how to call it and replace the ancient method (which was exactly the point of this question! and Thanks @markBaker for the great solution for my other question problem! :D Would you mind adding it as a solution there?

Comment: This allows you to use fromArray()... the fromArray() method calls the cell binder when it executes. As long as you've advised PHPExcel to use your value binder rather than the default one using PHPExcel_Cell::setValueBinder( new PHPExcel_Cell_MyValueBinder() ); then fromArray() will use your binder instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can extend the class and override the method you wish to extend the functionality of. This obeys the Open/Closed principle (Open for extension but closed for modification) of [SOLID programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) and you are making no changes to PHPExcel. You just need to use your new class over the extended class.

```
namespace MyPHPExcel;

class MyDataValueBinder extends \PHPExcel_Cell_DefaultValueBinder 
{
    public static function dataTypeForValue($pValue = null)
    {
      ...method body
    }
}

$returnValue = \MYPHPExcel\MyDataValueBinder::dataTypeForValue( $someValue );
```